# What is similar to postgresql uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() in a Django Model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

What would be similar to the postgresql schema below in a Django model? The current model, when doing an insert into the database, gives the error null value in column "account_uuid" violates not-null constraint. When generating the table directly in postgresql the insert works fine.

postgresql schema example:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    account_uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
);
```

django model attempt:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Account(models.Model):
    account_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
```

Comment: How do you perform the insert? By writing SQL yourself? Note that the `default` kwarg is not the same as setting a default on the database level.

Comment: the insert is done with psycopg2 using raw sql through another api server

Comment: As I said above the `default` kwarg does not set a default on the database level, it is something Django does when inserting new records. So their is no default set in the database. If you want to insert using raw queries you would have to provide the value or call a function to generate it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Is it added while you have data on the DB? If yes, You need to add the account_uuid value for each record.